# Node reference count does not get updated when adding referrer content

Tags: views, nodes

I am using:

[Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal) `7.41`

[Entity Reference Count](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_count) `7.x.1.dev`

I have two content types say *A* and *B*. The content type B has a field that refers to content type A.

I have added *count field* to content type A ( to get the count of *how many content of type B* refers to A ).

When I add a content of type B and refers to some content of type A, the count field in content type A does not get updated. However when I edit that particular node of type A and save it, the count updates.

I have used the count field to display on view and unless I explicitly save the content type A, I do not get the updated count.

Update:
The **node reference** is set in **commerce product** type, which is further rendered as **inline form using product reference** in the **content type B**. The **node reference refers to Content type A** and the **products are added as content type B**. I need to get the count of how many products are actually referring to content type A.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you custom code that ?

Comment: No, Nothing has been customized. Also, please see the edit in the question.